Two spinners statistics problem
I have two spinners:

I want to find the probability to spin a A, a E or a U. I built a table:

This table tells me that I have 13 in 25 of getting a A, an E or a U.
But I am going insane trying to figure this out from a mathematical perspective.
I thought it would be 2/5 (first spinner, chances of getting a A or a E) multiplied by 1/5 (chances of getting a U) = 3/25. But that's not the answer...
Trying to backtrace the numbers based on the result, I end up with XX + 1/5 (the second spinner) = 13/25. The only fraction fitting the bill is 8/25. So, in theory 8/25 is the probability of the first spinner having an A or an E. 8/25 + 1/5 = 13/25. So... how do I get to that 8/25? Well the only possible multiplication would be 2/5 * 4/5. So MAYBE it's 2/5 (the chances of getting an A or a E) multiplied by 4/5 -- the chances of... "not" hitting... OK I am lost help :-D
I did my best, I give up.

There are $3$ bad states on the left, and $4$ on the right.  Thus the probability of failing is $\frac 35\times \frac 45$.  Can you finish from here?

That's exactly what I was hoping for -- a lead, rather than a solution! THANK YOU! Working on it

A little more of a lead? What do I do with the "bad" states?

In a situation like this,  when there are multiple ways to win but only one way to lose,  it's often best to compute the probability of losing.  Then subtract from $1$.

One idea with your lead... the first spinner's chance is 2/5 MINUS multiplied the chances of winning in the next spinner (4/5). This plus the second spinner (1/5). Still ... not intuitive and probably not the solution. Now working with your next advice

This problem is small enough so that you can simply enumerate all 25 possible outcomes and count winners and losers. My first comment gives you a fast way to count the losers.

Your table is in fact a good "mathematical" way to find the answer.
To see the result more abstractly, the probability of an A or an E with the first spinner is (as you say) $2/5$. It's $1/5$ for a U on the second spinner.
For one or the other of those events the probability is
$$
\frac{2}{5} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{2}{25} = \frac{13}{25}.
$$
You subtract that $2/25$ in order not to count twice the times when you win on both spinners.

How did you work that 2/25 out from?

It's $(2/5) \times (1/5)$, which is the probability that you win twice. That has already been counted when you add the two separate probabilities. You can see that in your table.

Oh wow, thank you so much. This really clarified it!!!

You're welcome. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Wow what's the best dumb-student-friendly book you would recommend to deeeeeeppplllyyy understand this stuff?

Search the web for elementary combinatorics and pick a set of notes or a book that is the right level for you.
